# How find minimum value with System.Collections.Queue in C#

Tags: c#, queue

I have some problem with it. I need to find min and max values and swap them. This is my code, help me, pls, if u can. Thanks.

```
Queue myQueue = new Queue();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (var k = 0; k <= 5; k++) myQueue.Enqueue(rnd.Next(0, 10));
foreach (var d in myQueue) Console.Write("{0} ", d);
var min = (int)myQueue.Peek(); var max = 0;
var minInd = 0; var maxInd = 0;
for (var c = 0; c < myQueue.Count; c++)
{
   if ((int)myQueue.Peek() < min)
   {
       min = (int)myQueue.Peek();
       minInd = c;
   }
   if ((int)myQueue.Peek() > max)
   {
       max = (int)myQueue.Peek();
       maxInd = c;
   }
   foreach (var f in myQueue) Console.Write(" {0}", f);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a Queue for an algorithm like that?

Comment: Why are you using a `Queue` in the first place and not just a `List`?

Comment: And if you have to (because this looks like some homework assignment) then please take a look at the MSDN documention for the [Peek method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.peek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong class. `Queue` is for a list of stuff that need to be processed in order they arrive, not for working with sets of data. I edited your code to use a `List<>`, did some general cleanup, and added the swapping code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (var k = 0; k <= 5; k++)
    list.Add(rnd.Next(0, 10));

int min = 0;
int max = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] < min)
        min = i;
    if (list[i] > max)
        max = i;
}

Console.Write("Before: ");
foreach (var item in list)
    Console.Write("{0}", item);

var tmp = list[min];
list[min] = list[max];
list[max] = tmp;

Console.Write("\nAfter: ");
var queue = new Queue(list);
foreach (var item in queue)
    Console.Write("{0}", item);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I need to use Queue,this condition job

Comment: And if I want use only Queue, without List, is it possible?

Comment: The swapping is **not** possible. You must use a List here because Queue is not made for this purpose!

Comment: Glad I could be helpful. You could mark a post as the answer so other people have an easier time finding the solution to the same problem. :)

Comment: if i need to look at the first array(in list) before wrap in a queue, how can i do it?

Comment: Just add it before the `Queue queue = new Queue(list);` line. But hey, I already answered what you wanted, you could create a new question if you need to ask new questions.

Comment: So, I try to compile your code, but min not swaped with max

Comment: It happens to do so for me, do you want the list to be sorted from lowerst to highest?

Comment: Well, I found a crash in my code and updated it. I also report the old and new values now.

Comment: Thanks, so, I can't create new post, but i have a question about STack, how is it work? After compile, my Stack write in chaotic sequence. As it should be?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, there's no reason to use a queue here, also everything could be made much much easier.

```
var randomList = Enumerable.Range(0,5).ToList();
var min = randomList.Min();
var max = randomList.Max();
var minIndex = randomList.IndexOf(min);
var maxIndex = randomList.IndexOf(max);
randomList[minIndex] = max;
randomList[maxIndex] = min;
```

As you can see things don't have to be hard :)